# Spanish accent in email address - Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm using Node to send emails using Amazon SES.

I recently came across an error while sending an email to an email address containing a Spanish character (more specifically - Ã).

```
{"message":"Local address contains control or whitespace","code":"InvalidParameterValue","time":"2015-08-07T14:54:53.435Z","statusCode":400,"retryable":false,"retryDelay":30}
```

I'm not sure if SES accepts email address with these characters.

Has anyone come across this issue before?

Comment: Out of curiosity does the email address accept mail in the non-accented form?

Comment: Yes, it does. It failed for the one email address which had an accent character in the address.

Answer (score 2):

This is documented.

> **Destination**

> Represents the destination of the message, consisting of To:, CC:, and BCC: fields.

> By default, the string must be 7-bit ASCII. If the text must contain any other characters, then you must use MIME encoded-word syntax (RFC 2047) instead of a literal string. MIME encoded-word syntax uses the following form: `=?charset?encoding?encoded-text?=`. For more information, see [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047).

> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_Destination.html

Comment: How do you implement this? Is there a Ruby gem to handle this?